# Swift compiler error with generic type array as parameter

Tags: ios, generics, swift

I am trying to do something simple: Passing objects of a particular class `MyClass` into a function like so

```
func addObjects<T:MyClass>(objects:[T]){
}
```

But I get a compiler error

```
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
<unknown>:0: error: swift frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 254
```

If this truly is the compiler's fault, is there some workaround for this issue ?

Comment: shouldn't the type be `T[]`?

Comment: @kambala nope, since beta 3 arrays are written with enclosed braces

Answer (score 0):

Is that all of your code? This is working fine for me in Beta 3.

```
class MyClass{
}
func addObjects<T:MyClass>(objects:[T]){
}
addObjects([MyClass(), MyClass()])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func addObjects<T where T == MyClass>(objects: [T])
```

Though of course you don't need generics for this:

```
func addObjects(objects: [MyClass])
```